# Quote alignment inside rectangle for the Android app

Tags: bug, design, android-app

All quotes (strings started with `>` simbol) are not centered vertically in the Android app:

- raw:

  > quote
- picture from the Android app:

  > [image: andriod]
- picture from mobile web:

  > [image: mobile web]

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1626721325f7f)